# "I would follow you if that is what you wanted" Why is "would" used here?

Tags: conditional-constructions, if, irrealis-mood

- God knows that I would follow you if that is what you wanted.

This is a quote from a song called "God knows" (from an anime, The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya).

[image]

Why is "would" is used here though "is" is used in the if-clause.

I learnt at school that you use "would" in the main clause and the past tense in the if-clause when you refer to something not true.  So, according to what I learnt, it should be

- "I **would** follow you if that **was** what you **want**"

or

- "I **will** follow you if that **is** what you **want**".

Comment: There are a lot of related questions already (annoyingly, not always tagged very well, but if you search for will and would together you'll get many): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37616/second-conditional-with-will-not-would https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244857/conditional-sentences-will-vs-would

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "if + present, will + infinitive" and "if + present, would + infinitive".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would) Also [First, second and third conditional](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5030/first-second-and-third-conditional) and [Difference between "if + present, will + infinitive" and "if + present, would + infinitive"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65796/difference-between-if-present-will-infinitive-and-if-present-would), among others.

Comment: Note that the writers of *The Melancholy of Haruhi Suzumiya* aren't native Anglophones, so it's probably not a very good "study aid" for learning English. And it's *definitely* not a good source for example texts to be analyzed here (even if it so happens that on this specific occasion, there's nothing obviously wrong with the cited text - apart from the fact that actual Anglophones would almost certainly introduce one or more contractions).

Comment: Are you familiar with the so-called "first conditional" and "second conditional"?